# glossaries and see

Tags: glossaries

I have several acronyms that I want to list using the `glossaries` package. Some of these are rather peculiar, so I want to edit the acronym style.

These acronyms differ from the rest in that they could be used synonymously: basically, `RIVA` is in Latin, to be used in the main text, and `LAD` is in English; it is to be used in tables and diagrams. (This is just an example, there are more of such acronym pairs. I think it's rather confusing to use different terms for the same thing in a scientific paper, but those are the requirements I've got.)

My idea was to leave the glossary entry for `LAD` empty and just put a link to `RIVA` there; while the entry for `RIVA` contains the long form of both `RIVA` and (in parentheses) `LAD`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[nomain,xindy,acronym,toc,nopostdot,nogroupskip]{glossaries}

\setglossarystyle{list}
\renewcommand{\glsnumlistsep}{,}
\renewcommand{\glsnumlistlastsep}{:}


\newacronymstyle{teststyle}%
{%
  \ifglshaslong{\glslabel}{\glsgenacfmt}{\glsgenentryfmt}%
}%
{%
  \renewcommand*{\GenericAcronymFields}{%
    first={\the\glslongtok\space\protect\paren{\the\glsshorttok}},
    description={\the\glslongtok}}%
  \renewcommand*{\genacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \glsentrylong{##1}##2\space%
   (\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}})%
   }%
  \renewcommand*{\acronymentry}[1]{\acronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}}}%
  \renewcommand*{\acronymsort}[2]{##1}%
  \renewcommand*{\acronymfont}[1]{##1}%
  \renewcommand*{\firstacronymfont}[1]{\acronymfont{##1}}%
  \renewcommand*{\acrpluralsuffix}{\glspluralsuffix}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
                \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
                \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
                \ifglshasfield{see}{##1}
                    {##2}
                    {\glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2}%
                }%
}
\setacronymstyle{teststyle}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym[%
%           description={\nopostdesc},
            see={riva}]
            {lad}{LAD}{Left Anterior Descending}
\newacronym[%
        description={Ramus interventricularis anterior (Engl.: Left Anterior Descending},
        {riva}{RIVA}{Ramus interventricularis anterior}


%----------------------------------
\begin{document}
%~ \glsaddallunused
\printglossaries
\section{Test}
\gls{lad} and \gls{lad} again.
\clearpage
On this page, we have only \gls{riva}.
\clearpage
\gls{riva} means the same as \gls{lad} but is used in normal text, while \gls{lad} is used in tables and diagrams.

\end{document}
```

The interesting part of the code is the redefinition of `\glossentry`. I want to check whether the `see` field is set for an entry; if it is, print just the link, otherwise print the description and the link. However, the `\ifglshasfield`-directive seems to be ignored, so what I get is this:  [image: First page]

As you can see, the definition of `LAD` is printed although it should have been skipped. I guess that something is wrong with my `\ifglshasfield{see}{##1}…`statement -- but what? Another thing I do not understand is why the numberlist of `LAD` looks correct (it starts with `\space 1`, followed by a comma) but that of `RIVA` not (it starts with `\space ,`).

Finally, I have a question that has (not yet) to do with LaTeX, but with style: Both `RIVA` and `LAD` are referenced in the document, so both will have a numberlist -- as the picture shows. In my MWE, the numberlists are pretty short, but they will be longer in the final document. I don't like to clutter up the `LAD` entry -- I'd just like it to have the acronym, followed by "*see* RIVA": First, with no definition given, the numberlist could be interpreted as  the definition; second, the cross reference at the end of a potentially long line might be hard to find. Now, as both acronyms mean the same thing, do you think it might be possible to merge the numbers from the `LAD` numberlist into that of `RIVA`?  It would make sense from my premise to keep the line clean, but wouldn't it be confusing if one were looking for `RIVA` on a page where only `LAD` was referenced? If merging the numberlists would, indeed, make sense: Will the combined numberlist contain double numbers, or would a package-internal equivalent to `sort | uniq` take care of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base `glossaries` package doesn't actually store the value of the `see` key. The key, if present, automatically triggers the cross-reference when the entry is defined, so the value isn't saved. However, the [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) extension package does save it. The other advantage of `glossaries-extra` is that you can have different abbreviation styles for different categories.

The category is set using the new key `category` provided by `glossaries-extra`. The value is just a label of your choice (avoid special characters).

For example, you could assign the category `latin` for your Latin abbreviations and `xr` for your cross-reference abbreviations. There is an abbreviation style called `long-short-user` that can be used for abbreviations in the style *long* (*short*, *custom text*) or a similar `short-long-user` style for *short* (*long*, *custom text*). The custom text is by default obtained from the `user1` field. For example:

```
\setabbreviationstyle[latin]{long-short-user}

\newabbreviation[category=latin,
    user1={Left Anterior Descending}]
    {riva}{RIVA}{Ramus interventricularis anterior}
```

A new abbreviation style can be created for the `xr` category that's similar to `long-short` but the `description` field is set to the cross-reference (through `\glsxtrusesee`) and the number list is automatically suppressed with `nonumberlist`. For example:

```
\newabbreviationstyle{xrstyle}%
{%
  \renewcommand*{\CustomAbbreviationFields}{%
    name={\protect\glsabbrvfont{\the\glsshorttok}},
    sort={\the\glsshorttok},
    first={\protect\glsfirstlongfont{\the\glslongtok}%
     \protect\glsxtrfullsep{\the\glslabeltok}%
     (\protect\glsfirstabbrvfont{\the\glsshorttok})},%
    firstplural={\protect\glsfirstlongfont{\the\glslongpltok}%
     \protect\glsxtrfullsep{\the\glslabeltok}%
     (\protect\glsfirstabbrvfont{\the\glsshortpltok})},%
    plural={\protect\glsabbvfont{\the\glsshortpltok}},%
    nonumberlist,
    description={ \protect\glsxtrusesee{\the\glslabeltok}}}%
  \renewcommand*{\GlsXtrPostNewAbbreviation}{%
    \glshasattribute{\the\glslabeltok}{regular}%
    {%
      \glssetattribute{\the\glslabeltok}{regular}{false}%
    }%
    {}%
  }%
}%
{%
  \GlsXtrUseAbbrStyleFmts{long-short}%
}
```

Abbreviation styles must always be set before defining the abbreviations that use them:

```
\setabbreviationstyle[xr]{xrstyle}

\newabbreviation[category=xr,see={riva}]
 {lad}{LAD}{Left Anterior Descending}
```

The `category` can also be used to customize the glossary appearance without defining a new glossary style. This can be done by defining `\glsxtrpostdesc`*category*. For example,

```
\newcommand{\glsxtrpostdesclatin}{%
 \ifglshasfield{\glsxtruserfield}{\glscurrententrylabel}%
 { (Engl.: \glscurrentfieldvalue)}%
 {}%
}
```

This will automatically insert the translation after the description for the entries with the category set to `latin`.

I'm not sure whether or not it's a good idea to merge the number lists, but it can be done by automatically indexing RIVA whenever LAD is used. The `glossaries-extra` package provides hooks that are used after commands like `\gls` and `\glstext` in the form `\glsxtrpostlink`*category*, so for the `xr` category, this means defining `\glsxtrpostlinkxr`:

```
\newcommand{\glsxtrpostlinkxr}{%
  \glsfieldfetch{\glslabel}{see}{\xrlist}%
  \glsadd{\xrlist}%
}
```

This assumes that the value of the `see` key is a single label, so it wouldn't work for `see=[see also]lad` or `see={foo,bar}`. More general use would require a loop over `\xrlist`.

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[abbreviations,nomain,xindy,nogroupskip]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\newabbreviationstyle{xrstyle}%
{%
  \renewcommand*{\CustomAbbreviationFields}{%
    name={\protect\glsabbrvfont{\the\glsshorttok}},
    sort={\the\glsshorttok},
    first={\protect\glsfirstlongfont{\the\glslongtok}%
     \protect\glsxtrfullsep{\the\glslabeltok}%
     (\protect\glsfirstabbrvfont{\the\glsshorttok})},%
    firstplural={\protect\glsfirstlongfont{\the\glslongpltok}%
     \protect\glsxtrfullsep{\the\glslabeltok}%
     (\protect\glsfirstabbrvfont{\the\glsshortpltok})},%
    plural={\protect\glsabbvfont{\the\glsshortpltok}},%
    nonumberlist,
    description={ \protect\glsxtrusesee{\the\glslabeltok}}}%
  \renewcommand*{\GlsXtrPostNewAbbreviation}{%
    \glshasattribute{\the\glslabeltok}{regular}%
    {%
      \glssetattribute{\the\glslabeltok}{regular}{false}%
    }%
    {}%
  }%
}%
{%
  \GlsXtrUseAbbrStyleFmts{long-short}%
}

\newcommand{\glsxtrpostdesclatin}{%
 \ifglshasfield{\glsxtruserfield}{\glscurrententrylabel}%
 { (Engl.: \glscurrentfieldvalue)}%
 {}%
}

\newcommand{\glsxtrpostlinkxr}{%
  \glsfieldfetch{\glslabel}{see}{\xrlist}%
  \glsadd{\xrlist}%
}

\setabbreviationstyle[latin]{long-short-user}
\setabbreviationstyle[xr]{xrstyle}

\newabbreviation[category=latin,
user1={Left Anterior Descending}]
{riva}{RIVA}{Ramus interventricularis anterior}

\newabbreviation[category=xr,see={riva}]
 {lad}{LAD}{Left Anterior Descending}

\begin{document}

\printglossaries
\section{Test}
\gls{lad} and \gls{lad} again.
\clearpage
On this page, we have only \gls{riva}.
\clearpage
\gls{riva} means the same as \gls{lad} but is used in normal text,
while \gls{lad} is used in tables and diagrams.

\end{document}
```

(`glossaries-extra` automatically implements the package options `toc` and `nopostdot` by default.)

The first page looks like:

[image: image of page 1]

The second page:

[image: image of page 2]

This has the first use of `riva` displayed as:

> Ramus interventricularis anterior (RIVA, Left 
>   Anterior Descending)

This is the default first-use display style for `long-short-user`, but the parenthetical element can be altered by redefining `\glsxtruserparen`. For example:

```
\renewcommand*{\glsxtruserparen}[2]{%
  \glsxtrfullsep{#2}%
  (#1\ifglshasfield{\glsxtruserfield}{#2}{, Engl.: \glscurrentfieldvalue}{})%
}
```